# Check how many children in tuple

Tags: python, python-2.6

I would like to find how many children a parent has in a tuple, eg

```
tree = ('a', (
  ('b', ()),
  ('c', (
    ('e', ()),
    ('f', ()),
    ('g', ()),
  )),
  ('d', ()),
))
```

so if `a` has 3 children and `c` has 3 children I would like to run some code, I have had no idea so far on how to approach this though.

By children - I mean the length of the tuple AFTER the string? `e.g: ('c', ( ..., ..., ...) )` - `'c'` is the string and `(..., ..., ...)` is tuple with length of 3?

Comment: By children - you mean  the length of the tuple AFTER the string? e.g: `('c', ( ..., ..., ...) )` - `'c'` is the string and `(..., ..., ...)` is tuple with length of 3?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a dictionary as a data structure (if the order of items doesn't matter) or a `namedtuple` (if it does)?

Comment: Would *named tuples* in the `collections` modules be better for you?

Comment: I am using this for a ternary tree and I would like input to be in a tuple which I can sort out but I need to check as a tuple, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Let's first introduce an easy way to iterate over all the tree nodes (DFS):

```
def walk(t):
    yield t
    for child in t[1]:
        for p in walk(child):
            yield p
```

Let's see how it works...

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint(list(walk(tree)))
[('a', (('b', ()), ('c', (('e', ()', ()), ('g', ()))), ('d', ()))),
 ('b', ()),
 ('c', (('e', ()), ('f', ()), ('g', ()))),
 ('e', ()),
 ('f', ()),
 ('g', ()),
 ('d', ())]
```

Then we need to find your given parent and count its children. Let's start with a generic find routine:

```
def find(pred, seq):
    '''returns the first element from seq that satisfied pred'''
    for elem in seq:
        if pred(elem):
            return elem
    # not found?
    raise Exception('Not found')
```

Then let's adapt it to search for nodes with a given name in a given tree:

```
def findNode(t, label):
    return find(lambda node: node[0] == label, walk(t))
```

In order to count children of a node, we simply need to count the second value of the tuple:

```
def childrenCount(node):
    return len(node[1])
```

Let's mix the two together:

```
for label in "abcdefg":
    print label, childrenCount(findNode(tree, label))
```

Result:

```
a 3
b 0
c 3
d 0
e 0
f 0
g 0
```

---

@thg435 has suggested to use a dictionary instead. Let's do this:

```
def childrenNames(parent):
    return tuple(child[0] for child in parent[1])

treedict = {t[0] : childrenNames(t) for t in walk(tree)}
```

This gives you a nice dictionary, into which you can look up directly (as @thg435 has suggested).

```
>>> pprint(treedict)
{'a': ('b', 'c', 'd'),
 'b': (),
 'c': ('e', 'f', 'g'),
 'd': (),
 'e': (),
 'f': (),
 'g': ()}
>>> pprint(sorted(treedict.keys()))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> pprint(len(treedict['a']))
3
```

Comment: This counts the letters in a string can I just put in a tuple, eg:

    `tree = ('a', (
      ('b', ()),
      ('c', (
        ('e', ()),
        ('f', ()),
        ('g', ()),
      )),
      ('d', ()),
    )) 
    for label in tree:
        print label, childrenCount(findNode(tree, label))`

Answer (score 0):

First let's convert the data structure to something more appropriate:

```
def convert(node, d):
    key, sub = node
    d[key] = [convert(s, d) for s in sub]
    return d[key]

newtree = {}
convert(tree, newtree)
```

This creates a dictionary like `{key: list of children}`, which you can query directly:

```
 print len(newtree['c'])  # 3
```

Comment: Good idea about the dict, but the output doesn't really dig it http://ideone.com/Dkcoe

Comment: That is good so I can check the length of the dictionary but why does a return `[[], [[], [], []], []]` I would like in this case `[[], [], []]` so the length is 3.

Comment: @AngusMoore: huh? the length of `newtree[a]` is 3.